Show a set is compact or not on $C[0, 1]$
Let $$S = \left\{ x_n(t) = \frac{1}{1 + t^n} : n \in \mathbb{N} \right\}$$ Determine whether $ S $ is compact in the space $C[0, 1]$
If I understand the task correctly, $C[0,1]$ is the space of all continuous functions on $[0, 1]$. In order to show whether the set is compact or not, we need to show if it is bounded and closed, but I don't have any idea how to start. Any help will be very appreciated
Thank you very much!

It is not true that closed and bounded sets are compact. Look at subsequential limits to answer the question.

You must be careful that $C[0,1]$ is infinite dimensional. Therefore, compact is not equivalent to bounded and closed, it is stronger. For example, the closed unit ball is always bounded and closed but never compact (whatever norm you use).
Talking about norms, since $C[0,1]$ is infinite dimensional, its topology depends on the chosen norm and $S$ may be compact or not in function of the norm you use. From now on, I will assume you use the classical norm on $C[0,1]$,
$$
\|f\| = \max_{[0,1]} |f|.
$$
Let us show that $S$ is not compact despite it is bounded and closed (but it may not be if you change the norm, it may become compact). Indeed, consider the sequence $(x_n)_{n \geqslant 0}$ whose terms belong to $S$ by defintion. If $S$ is compact, there is an increasing function $\varphi : \mathbb{N} \rightarrow \mathbb{N}$ such that $(x_{\varphi(n)})$ converges. Call $l$ the limit.
Limits for $\|\cdot\|$ are uniform limits and it implies pointwise limit. If $t < 1$,
$$
l(t) = \lim_{n \rightarrow +\infty} x_{\varphi(n)}(t) = \lim_{n \rightarrow +\infty} \frac{1}{1 + t^{\varphi(n)}} = 1.
$$
And if $t = 1$,
$$
l(1) = \lim_{n \rightarrow +\infty} x_{\varphi(n)}(1) = \lim_{n \rightarrow +\infty} \frac{1}{1 + 1^{\varphi(n)}} = \frac{1}{2}.
$$
We deduce that $l$ is not continuous, which contradicts $l \in C[0,1]$. By contradiction, $S$ is not compact.

Thank you very much. Is this the subsequential limit mentioned in the comment above? And also, in this case, φ(n) is equal to n (because of the definition of S)? And if possible, can you show how S is closed?

Yes it is. No, $\varphi(n)$ is any increasing sequence of integer (so it diverges toward infinity). It is the function related to the definition of sub-sequential limit.
To show that $S$ is closed, since the sequence $(x_n)$ has no converging sub-sequence, $S$ is discrete in $C[0,1]$, thus it is closed.

Thank you very much
